# ServiceStack Deserialization not building an object

Tags: c#, servicestack, json-deserialization

I'm using servicestack to deserialize a JSON I got from a web service into an object.
The process works (no exceptions) but I have no access to the classes inside the deserialized object.

my code calls this:

```
  LoginResultModel result = new LoginResultModel
            {
                Avatars = new Avatars(),
                Country = new Country(),
                RootObject = new RootObject()
            };


    result = client.Post<LoginResultModel>(URL, postData);
```

Once I get back the result (of type LoginResultModel), I cant access anything inside of it!
Intellisense wont help - "result." dont show anything related to that class.

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the hierarchy? (Weird since no exceptions are thrown). What am I doing wrong?

JSON in Deserialized form (Used json2Csharp):

```
 public class LoginResultModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// IsLogedIn method 
    /// </summary>

    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public Avatars Avatars { get; set; }
    public RootObject RootObject { get; set; }

}

public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string A2 { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public int PhonePrefix { get; set; }
}

public class Avatars
{
    public string Small { get; set; }
    public string Medium { get; set; }
    public string Large { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int AffiliateID { get; set; }
    public Avatars Avatars { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }
    public bool AllowCommunity { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public int TokenExpirationInMinutes { get; set; }
    public bool IsKYCRequired { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LoginResultModel` class does not contain any public properties. So there is nothing to serialise, and you will then have an empty result.

What you have done is created other classes within the `LoginResultModel` which I believe you meant to implement as properties.

What you should really do is create the classes like this:

```cs
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string A2 { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public int PhonePrefix { get; set; }
}

public class Avatars
{
    public string Small { get; set; }
    public string Medium { get; set; }
    public string Large { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int AffiliateID { get; set; }
    public Avatars Avatars { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }
    public bool AllowCommunity { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public int TokenExpirationInMinutes { get; set; }
    public bool IsKYCRequired { get; set; }
}
```

Where `LoginResultModel` has properties of the type of the other classes:

```
public class LoginResultModel
{
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public Avatars Avatars { get; set; }
    public RootObject RootObject { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your action method you will need to populate the `LoginResultModel` with an instance of those objects:

```
public class MyLoginService : Service
{
    public LoginResultModel Post(LoginRequest request)
    {
        // Your login logic here
        return new LoginResultModel {
            Country = new Country { Name = "United States", A2 = "Something", Code = 1, PhonePrefix = 555},
            Avatars = new Avatars { Small = "small.png", Medium = "medium.png", Large = "large.png" },
            RootObject = new RootObject { 
                CID = 123,
                Username = "",
                ...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I kinda see what you mean but after editing the code (Edited my post to reflect how the new code looks like) I now get error like this:


Type defenition should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'LoginResultModel', got string starting with: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

Comment: @Yosi199 Now that you have edited the question, I can see better what you are trying to do. I realise now you are calling a 3rd party api and not your own ServiceStack service. Your problem is the 3rd party response is not returning JSON which the ServiceStack client expects. It is returning HTML, which likely includes some error message. You will only be able to resolve this by ensuring the request you make is correct and understood by the 3rd party api, so that it returns JSON.

Comment: You are right - I'm sending a wrong request. I'm not getting the JSON back since in my request I didn't add a header. 

I think I've used service stack JsonServiceClient.post wrongly - I need to send my request with a header (content-type). Should I resort to using WebRequest? or is a way to send a request along with header using service stack?

Comment: @Yosi199 The `JsonServiceClient` does automatically set the `ContentType` to `application/json` and your request `client.Post<LoginResultModel>(URL, postData)` does look right. But if the postData isn't what the service expects it may ignore the contentType to provide the error. It's difficult to know with 3rd party apis as there are no REST standards. I suspect the API you are calling ignores the header when something goes wrong. It's best to read their api documentation on how they handle errors. Postman extension for Chrome is a good way to test API responses.

Comment: I need to send content-type to be "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Can I somehow send this content type using service stack?

Comment: @Yosi199 In that case you would be best to use a standard `WebRequest` post as the `JsonServiceClient` will serialise requests to JSON not the form URLencoding required by the API, which is why it won't like the response.

Comment: @Yosi199 You're welcome. Good luck with your project.